# I want to override document in firestore flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, geolocation

I have collection named **location** in firestore in it i have document with auto generated id 
fields **longitude** and **latitude**. I want to update these two fields when ever the location is changed. My problem is when the location is changed value is added in **longitude** and **latitude** but their id changed means that these fields did't updated instead of updating it adds new one. My code is:
**Model class**

```
class Node{
  String longitude;
  String latitude;
  String id;

  Node({this.longitude, this.latitude, this.id});

  Node.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> data, String id):
  longitude = data['longitude'],
  latitude = data['latitude'],
  id=id;

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap(){
    return {
      'longitude':longitude,
      'latitude' : latitude
    };
  }

}
```

**FirestoreService for adding location in firestore**

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

import 'node.dart';
class FirestoreService {
  static final FirestoreService _firestoreService =
  FirestoreService._internal();
  Firestore _db = Firestore.instance;

  FirestoreService._internal();

  factory FirestoreService() {
    return _firestoreService;
  }

  Future<void> addNode(Node node)async{
    return await _db.collection('location').add(node.toMap());

  }


  Future<void> updateNode(Node node){
    return _db.collection('location').document(node.id).
    updateData(node.toMap());
  }
}
```

**In this class i have streame builder that fetch my location and also display my long and lat to textview**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_realtime_location/services/geolocator_service.dart';
import 'firestore_service.dart';
import 'node.dart';

class MapLocationSendFirestore extends StatefulWidget {
 MapLocationSendFirestore({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MapLocationSendFirestoreState createState() => _MapLocationSendFirestoreState();
}

class _MapLocationSendFirestoreState extends State<MapLocationSendFirestore> {
  final GeolocatorService geoService=GeolocatorService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
  body: StreamBuilder<Position>(
    stream: geoService.getUserLocation(),
    builder: (context, snapshoot){
      Node node= Node(longitude: snapshoot.data.longitude.toString(), 
                latitude: snapshoot.data.latitude.toString());
              FirestoreService().addNode(node);
      if(!snapshoot.hasData) 
      {
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      }
      return Center(
        child: Text('${snapshoot.data.latitude} and ${snapshoot.data.longitude}'),


      );
    }),
    );
  }
}
```

[Image of my firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4U1sv.png)

Comment: Just to clarify, you want a single document in the collection that changes values with location changes?

Comment: yes. i want to change longitude and latitude. means that if value changed it adds in single document no like in the picture that i have many documents created. I want ingle document that changes every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution. First i was not getting id after getting id i came to know that i have to use static id in order to override my document. So a solution is:

```
Future<void> setNode(Node node) async {
  print('Id is: ${node.id}');
  return await _db.collection('location').document('dani').
  setData(node.toMap());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `addNode` and `updateNode` functions that add and update documents respectively, use `setNode` that uses firestore's `setData` functions, which will create the document if it doesn't exist and overwrites an existing document. It should look something like this:

```
Future<void> setNode(Node node){
  return _db.collection('location').document(node.id).
  setData(node.toMap());
}
```

You'll have to find a way to set the id of the node in another place if you need multiple nodes in the `location` collection.

Comment: find the problem that i am not geting id from: `return _db.collection('location').document(node.id).
  setData(node.toMap());`
as in image you can see the documents i coped the id of one document and passed inside of my constructor `Node node= Node(longitude: latitude: , id: '8dxyalF54f1G8mxy4EIW');` 
Then i am getting override this id. So kindly tell me how to this id same very time while creating first time as well. because this id is auto incremented. How to change it as static id?